# Incremental Numbering while skipping over certain cells

Tags: excel, numbers, conditional-statements, rows, countif

I am trying to do an incremental numbering in Excel, but for a specific condition. If the condition does not match, then it should keep the existing cell details.

Image:

[image]

As you can see from the picture, I want to create a numbering list in column B, which is based off information shown in the corresponding row in column D. So on the second row, I would the counting to start at "1" and then continue to expand only as the count of "is_null" and "equal" grows. At the same time, I want it to skip over the green and blue cells and keep the contents as is.

As of right now, I have done the following formula:
`=COUNTIF($D$1:D2,"is_null")+COUNTIF($D$1:D2,"equals")`

This does the proper numbering, however it over-writes the green and blue cells instead of keeping them as "A" and "stop" respectively.

If someone can help me with that issue, then I should be good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the value should be if in Column D you find the String "set_path" or "stop", but if these are always the same (i.e. "a" if Column D = "set_path" and "stop" if Column D = "stop"), you could achieve your desired results with the following formula:

`=IF(AND(D2<>"set_path",D2<>"stop"),COUNTIF($D$1:D2,"is_null")+COUNTIF($D$1:D2,"equals"),IF(D2="set_path","a",IF(D2="stop","stop","")))`

**UPDATE:**

Using VBA you could leave the contents of the cell as they are without overwriting them with a formula using the code below:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required.
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column D

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Then 'if cell is empty add formula
        ws.Cells(i, "B").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R1C4:RC[2],""is_null"")+COUNTIF(R1C4:RC[2],""equals"")"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

**Second Update:**

I've now adapted the formula to increment the letters by one if "set_path" is found in Column D (Please bear in mind that this will go from A-Z and then it will start going through symbols as per ASCII table, so you might have to amend this if you want alternate behavior):

`=IF(AND(D2<>"set_path",D2<>"stop"),COUNTIF($D$1:D2,"is_null")+COUNTIF($D$1:D2,"equals"),IF(D2="set_path",IFERROR(CHAR(COUNTIF($D$2:D2,"set_path")+64),""),IF(D2="stop","stop","")))`

Comment: The formula is ALMOST there! The only thing is that I also need to do an incremental increase for "set_path". In the current case, anytime "set_path" is seen, "a" is put in. If you can think of a formula that has 1st "set_path" as "a", 2nd "set_path" as "b" and so on, that would be perfect!

Comment: @Sunny I've updated my answer with a second formula to do what you expected, please could you accept my response as an answer if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: Works just as expected. Thank you so much!